# Running a PL/SQL block using Java

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, spring-jdbc

Say I have following procedure -

```
DECLARE
   enqueue_options     dbms_aq.enqueue_options_t;
   message_properties  dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
   message_handle      RAW(16);
   message             custom_payload_type;

BEGIN
   message := custom_payload_type('Subject','Body');

   dbms_aq.enqueue(queue_name => 'my_demo_queue',           
         enqueue_options      => enqueue_options,       
         message_properties   => message_properties,     
         payload              => message,               
         msgid                => message_handle);

   COMMIT;
END;
```

Using spring jdbc I already created a datasource>
I Dont have this procedure stored in data base. These procedure hardcoded in java side.

How to run this SQL block using java?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to run this SQL block using java?

Answer (score 4):

Use a `CallableStatement`:

```
String plsql = "..... your code in here ...";
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(plsql);
cstmt.execute();
```

Comment: what is dataSource here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the stored procedure in your Java code as a String, you need to create the stored procedure with *Connection.createStatement()* and then execute it with something like *prepareCall("{call  your_procedure_name()}")* and *execute*.

See [Creating Stored Procedures in Java DB with SQL Scripts or JDBC API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#creating_javadb_sql_jdbc) for more detailed steps. Or [this page](http://Using%20JDBC%20CallableStatements%20to%20Execute%20Stored%20Procedures) for the Oracle equivalent.

Rough code steps are below. For brevity, I ommited try catch blocks, setting input parameters for the call statement, registering output parameters, etc. Like I said, the full answer can be obtained by extracting relevant paragraphs from the documentation links I posted above.

```
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
String createProcedure = "create procedure enque_message(" + ... ;
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(createProcedure);

CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call enque_message()}");
boolean hadResults = cStmt.execute();
while (hadResults) {
    ResultSet rs = cStmt.getResultSet();
    // process result set
}
```

Comment: The OP is trying to run an anonymous PL/SQL block, despite referring to it as a procedure. Wrapping it in a procedure might be a good idea, but that would normally be a one-off task done in the schema build directly in the DB, not something the application would do.